# Customise A URL With Checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, url, search, checkbox

I'm making [a website](http://jeremyblazedesign.com/rwthemefinder/) which basically searches another website. All I need to do is:

When the checkbox labelled 'Responsive' is checked, add the extension 'responsive+' to the end of this url: www.realmacsoftware.com/addons/search/rapidweaver?q=theme+ (resulting in www.realmacsoftware.com/addons/search/rapidweaver?q=theme+responsive+)

I'd rather not use any JS if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST to _self and then header redirect server side to the desired URL.

The HTML should read:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type=checkbox name="query[]" value="responsive"> Responsive<br/>
        <input type=checkbox name="query[]" value="dark"> Dark<br/>
    </form>
```

And an php example:

```
<?php // this should be in the beginning of the document
if( ! empty($_POST['query'])) {
    $query_string = implode('+', array_map('urlencode', $_POST['query']));
    header('Location: http://www.realmacsoftware.com/addons/search/rapidweaver?q=theme+'.$query_string);
}
?>
```

Comment: I've applied all of the things you've suggested but it still doesn't appear to work. Do I have to publish it or something first?

Comment: What did you mean by redirect server side? @core1024

Comment: I mean that the server tells the browser to navigate to another page. See here for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_redirect

Comment: As I can see your server is not PHP enabled and I had an error too, but it's fixed now - the closing tag shouldn't be `php?>` instead just `?>`

Comment: Is there anything special I need to do with the submit button? I have currently got `<input type=submit class="button" value="Show me!">`

Comment: Your server does not support PHP. If you are administrator/root on your server you should install php this to work. When it's ready if you 'view source' of your page you shouldn't see the php code. It must be visible to the server only.

Comment: Instead of uploading a index.html file, do I need to upload a index.php file or something? And the cPanel at MacHighway seems to be telling me that PHP _is_ installed.

Comment: I have used PHP on this server before. See here: http://jeremyblazedesign.com/support/